# Jenkins ERROR: Failed to parse POMs java.io.IOException: Cannot run program error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter

In jenkins I am forcing the execution to happen in one of the slaves.
in jenkins configuration I have updated the JAVA_HOME and MAVEN location to the location where its installed in the slave. When I start the build in jenkins I receive the following error

```
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/jmeter/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java" (in directory "/home/jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/workspace/MyProject"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

PS : /home/jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/workspace/MyProject - This directory got created and does exist in the slave machine

Can someone please share their expertise in resolving it ?

Answer (score 4):

I needed to add `Tool location` of JDK8 for machine i run test on.

[image: Machine setup]

Answer (score 2):

looks like there is a problem in the MVN installation. PLS make sure in the global config that you have the required mvn installation.

jenkins-->manage-->configure look for **Maven installations**  and use automatic installation for the required version

make sure you have the JDK installation in the same config file

Answer (score 1):

After wasting one day trying with different things going through different suggestions I got nothing. But, it was actually very simple. Please add the JDK path as bellow to your JDK Path in Jenkins-

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the JDK in the `Meta Data`,The `JAVA_HOME` of system is not work for build.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Maven version selected into the Manage Jenkins->Global Configurations->Maven->Maven Installations->Install from Apache->Version  is same as installed on the server and your maven project.

Answer (score 0):

You might have left out a few dependencies resulting in this issue. 
Go back and download java and set the path as before:

To download, use
$yum -y install java-1.8*

Set the path to
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.amzn2.0.1.x86_64

Note: Get your path using command
find /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8* | head -n 3

Comment: For the original poster as well as people who come across this answer in the future, it would be helpful to elaborate on what these steps actually mean and how they solve the problem. Also, please use formatting to make code and commands more readable. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved after adding `maven_home` and providing the path in the global properties.

Go to: *Jenkins* ⟶ *Manage Jenkins* ⟶ *Global Properties* ⟶ *MAVEN_HOME* [C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3]

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Please allow me to add some constructive feedback: Next time try adding a good formatted answer and also try to avoid spelling mistakes. You can go through [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) if you need further information.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs into this. I was getting this error because someone setup the JDK in Global Tool Configuration to download a windows version of the JDK, but my instance of jenkins is running on linux. Once I made the change to use a linux version of the JDK my issue was resolved.