# ERROR: Failed to parse POMs java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/java"

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting this error when trying to run any new build. I checked other answers but they are not working for me.

[image: error log]

Comment: How is this question related to `selenium`?

Answer (score 2):

The error mentions clearly of an IOException with last mentioning as “System could not find the file specified”

Please check the directory where you have to place the file. Maybe it is corrupted and code is unable to read it. Try placing a new file and read it.

The error message states that. However, it would be helpful if you can provide the whole context on what you intend to perform with your code and even paste the code here for us to help.

I am not sure if you are looking at jenkins . This might help:

[Jenkins ERROR: Failed to parse POMs java.io.IOException: Cannot run program error=2, No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750422/jenkins-error-failed-to-parse-poms-java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-erro)

Comment: Thanks @adarsh kumar , 
I found the problem , i required to download few more maven dependency.
Now this is working fine for me .:)
Appreciate your help !!!